# Check if multiple rows exist in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a two dataframes. I want to see if specific rows (in its entirety) exist in the other dataframe. Example rows from df_subset:

```
id    category    value    date
1     A           10       01-01-15
3     C           10       03-01-15
```

The other df_full:

```
id    category    value    date
1     A           10       01-01-15
2     B           10       02-01-15
3     C           10       03-01-15
4     D           16       04-01-15
```

Is there someway to check if the rows of one dataframe exists in another? Something like this (obviously this does not work): `df_subset in df_full`, exist?

```
> True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with inner join (by default) with [`DataFrame.equals`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) for compare with `df_subset`:

```
print (pd.merge(df_subset,df).equals(df_subset))
True
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use [merge(..., indicator=True)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) method:

```
In [14]: pd.merge(df1, df2, indicator=True, how='outer')
Out[14]:
   id category  value      date      _merge
0   1        A     10  01-01-15        both
1   3        C     10  03-01-15        both
2   2        B     10  02-01-15  right_only
3   4        D     16  04-01-15  right_only
```

Answer (score 3):

***using `numpy`***

```
(df_subset.values[:, None] == df_full.values).all(2).any(1).all()

True
```

***timing***
[image]

***explanation***

```
# using [:, None] to extend into new dimension at
# take advantage of broadcasting
a1 = df_subset.values[:, None] == df_full.values

     # ━> third dimension ━>
     # ━━━━> axis=2 ━━━>
# 1st dim
---->[[[ True  True  True  True]   # │
       [False False  True False]   # │ second dimension
       [False False  True False]   # │ axis=1
       [False False False False]]  # ↓

 # axis=0
 ---->[[False False  True False]   # │ 
       [False False  True False]   # │ second dimension
       [ True  True  True  True]   # │ axis=1
       [False False False False]]] # ↓

# first row of subset with each row of full 
[[[ True  True  True  True]  <-- This one is true for all 
  [False False  True False]
  [False False  True False]
  [False False False False]]

# second row of subset with each row of full 
 [[False False  True False] 
  [False False  True False]
  [ True  True  True  True]  <-- This one is true for all
  [False False False False]]]
```

---

```
a2 = a1.all(2)

#   ┌─ first row of subset all equal
[[ True False False False]
 [False False  True False]]
#               └─ second row of subset all equal
```

---

```
a3 = a2.any(1)

#  ┌─ first row of subset matched at least one row of full
[ True  True]
#        └─ second row of subset matched at least one row of full
```

---

```
a3.all()

True
```

***ALL ROWS OF `df_subset` ARE IN `df_full`***

Comment: I extended array to third dimension. all(2) is along third axis. I'll update post to make it clearer

Comment: Ya, it is really complicated. Numpy is for me complicated, I prefer pandas.